# How to put a conditional break point while debugging in pyscripter?

Tags: python, debugging, pyscripter

My question may seem bizarre.

I am debugging a program in python with portable python, pyscripter.

Is it possible to ask pyscripter to do this? :

"Run the program until `my_variable` 's value become equal to 10, then stop at that point, and let me debug it line by line (using F7 or F8)"

I want some sort of breakpoint that activates when a variable gets some specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PyScripter can do this. It is called conditional breakpoint.

Put a breakpoint, open `Breakpoints` tab, right-click on your breakpoint to bring context menu where you can add a condition (python expression)